# Geometry with triangle ABC

Tags: geometry, proof-verification, vectors, euclidean-geometry, triangles

My question is...
I want to know your another solution.
or I want to know if my solution is appropriate.
and I’d appreciate some feedback on my work.

> $E$ is midpoint of $\overline{BC}$.
>   $\overline{AD} : \overline{DE}$ = 4:3
>   Find the $\overline{AF} : \overline{FC}$.
>   [image]

Comment: In the future, please use MathJax to format your mathematics, because this makes your question more search-engine friendly. Having said that, though, the way you've typeset your question is beautiful and very easy to read.

Comment: @John In fact, that's why I always write the problem with MathJax in the first place. (for search).

Comment: @mina_world: All the text should be actual text. Someone might remember that there was some recent question involving, say, the terms "midpoint" and "collinear"; since "collinear" is trapped in the image, it doesn't get read. (This isn't the best example, but I hope you take my meaning: You want as much of your work as possible to be searchable.) As I mentioned in a comment to another item of yours: screen readers (for the visually impaired) need *text*. (Granted, MathJax is also problematic for screen readers, but there are occasional *words* in there. :)

Comment: While I'm handing out friendly advice :) ... It would be really helpful to provide more-informative titles to your questions. "Geometry with triangle ABC", "Geometry with circle and triangle", "Geometry with triangle" don't tell the reader what to expect. Moreover, if these questions had come up in a search, the searcher wouldn't be able to tell which questions are actually relevant. (Years from now, when *you* decide to look back through *your own* questions for something that could help someone, you won't be able to tell which is which. Try to give questions titles that help "Future You".)

Comment: @mina_world I didn't realize the question was formatted with MathJax already. The fact that it was imported as an image fooled me.

Comment: @Blue I will not be satisfied with everything, but I will always do my best. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 12):

Usually problems like this have one-line solution using [Menelaus's theorem](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Menelaus%27s_theorem). For triangle $ACE$ and line $BDF$:

$$
\left|\frac{AF}{FC}\frac{CB}{BE}\frac{ED}{DA}\right| = 1,\qquad
\frac{AF}{FC} = \frac{BE}{CB}\frac{DA}{ED} = \frac12 \frac{4}{3} = \frac 23\\
$$

Comment: Very nice! thank you very much.

Answer (score 9):

Draw a paralel to $BF$ through $E$ and let it cuts $AC$ in $P$.

[image]

Then by [Thales theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem) we have $$FP:PC = BE:EC = 1:1$$

Again by Thales theorem we have $$AF:FP= AD:DE = 4:3$$

So, if $FP = 3x$ then $PC =3x$ and $AF = 4x$ so $$ AF:FC = 4x:6x = 2:3$$

Comment: Very nice! thank you very much.

Comment: In what country do they call it Thales theorem?

Comment: Grecee, Croatia, Romania, Bulgaria, Serbia, Bosna and Hercegovina, Austria,...

Comment: I thought only in France and Switzerland.

Comment: Well, I didn't know that ...

Comment: @BPP If "Thales theorem" is not the way you call it, how do you call it and in which area of the world ?

Comment: They also call it Thales theorem in Italian, Arabic, Portuguese and Russian.

Comment: @JeanMarie In some countries it is called the [intercept theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem) since Thales discovered [another theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27s_theorem). As for the names of these two theorems, wikipedia gives a partial answer [here](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_inscrit_dans_un_demi-cercle#Appellation) and [here](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_de_Thal%C3%A8s#Enseignement_et_appellations).

Comment: @BPP Thanks for the precision.

Answer (score 2):

There is a solution using the following

**Theorem** : If two triangles have their bases on a same line and have a common height, we have :

$$\frac{A_1}{A_2} = \frac{L_1}{L_2}$$

meaning that the ratio of their areas is the same as the ratio of the lengths of their bases. See for example http://www.madeiracityschools.org/userfiles/376/Classes/17052/Ratio%20of%20Areas-0.pdf.

Take a look at the following picture where the lower case letters indicate areas of the corresponding triangles.

[image]

We can write the following linear system where equations (1) to (4) are direct consequences of the upsaid theorem, the last equation (5) being a normalization (we are free to take the area unit we want ; taking $70$ is the result of an "afterthought", in order to provide integer values ) :

$$\begin{cases}
(1)&x/z&=&4/3\\
(2)&y/v&=&4/3\\
(3)&v+z&=&w\\
(4)&v+w+y&=&x+z\\
(5)&v+w+x+y+z&=&70
\end{cases}$$

out of which one gets

$$(v,w,x,y,z) \ = \ (6, 21, 20, 8, 15).$$

The looked-for ratio is thus, using (backwards) the above theorem :

$$\frac{AF}{FC}=\frac{area(AEF)}{area(ECF)}=\frac{y+v}{w}=\frac{14}{21}=\frac{2}{3}.$$

Remark : Had we taken $1$ instead of $70$ in the RHS of equation (5), we would have obtained the same final result, but with unaesthetic fraction computations.

Answer (score 1):

Let me put together the two articles that answered my question.

[image]